# R: Load data directly without lazyload promise

Tags: r, database, download, promise, lazy-loading

I have a package with a number of csvs that I've saved as compressed `.RData` files. I'm trying to load them e.g. with

```
mysamples <- data("samples")
```

But `data("samples")` loads samples as a promise which is only evaluated if called e.g.

```
samples
```

Is there a way to load data into memory directly, rather than lazyloading as a promise? Or do I have to

```
data(samples)
samples
mysamples <- samples
```

for every dataset? I was hoping `data("samples", envir = .GlobalEnv)` would do that but it doesn't. Is there a different function for this? I've tried `load` but it cannot open the compressed file. Thanks for any help.

Edit: if I turn off lazy loading then I can use

```
data("samples")
mysamples <- samples
```

But then I have 2 files in the environment rather than one, so would have to `rm(samples)` which again means 3 operations required for each file to assign a database as named object in the environment. Compared to 1 for e.g. `read.csv()`. Am I missing a simple function here or is this just the way it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

my.data <-package.name::dataset.name

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This results in "Error: 'samples' is not an exported object from 'namespace:gbm.auto'". Rstudio shows that none of the datasets are listed within gbm.auto, assumedly it only lists the functions which are in the namespace? I haven't yet documented my data (still getting the hang of packaging), but that doesn't look like it adds to the namespace file in any case. Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess you have to add the data as an exported object from your package. I am not sure how to do that. So perhaps another question on here will answer that.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i'd turned off lazy loading to try to fix this, which meant your solution didn't then work. Now it does. Cheers!

Comment: This only works for lazy data if the package is attached i.e. library(pkgname)